# "Batch process" in qgis or simple program for resave multiple vector files into files with different CRS

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

Right now i,m using QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa, and i wonder if in QGIS there is any feature or plugin to resave multiple vector files that using CRS "A" into vector files using CRS "B" in 1 execution step (Batch process). I mean not save it one by one.

so far i find the closest solution (but no CRS changing) is batch processing for selected features from the toolbox - on pic
[image]

But this feature does not have option to change the output CRS. It would be a great help if someone know how to do this in QGIS or in another standalone program that can do this kind of batch processing.

Comment: There is a reproject tool in the Processing toolbox. Can be used in Batch Processing as well. Will that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Reproject** tool instead of Save selected features. It can be used in Batch Processing as well.

Comment: addition: so far, it only works if data input are  selected data from filesystem not open layers (active layer that opened in qgis at the mean time).

Comment: @MaruliManullang - Do you mean that you selected the open layers (by clicking the 3 dots for the input layer as seen in your screenshot) and they did not reproject? I just tested this on QGIS 2.12.3 for Win7 and it works fine.

Comment: @Joseph - Yes, that what i mean. i wonder this thing has to do with QGIS Pisa version or the size/how many features totally that want to be reprojected. Use windows 7 also. The error message that i got is " 'NoneType object has no attribute 'pendingFields' "

Comment: @MaruliManullang - Perhaps it is an issue with the _Processing_ plugin. You can try updating this (if you haven't already) from the toolbar: _Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins_. I think the latest version you can use for QGIS Pisa is 2.10.3 as mentioned in the [repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing/).

Comment: @Joseph, it was updated. but this issue still occur.

Comment: @MaruliManullang - Perhaps install the latest version of QGIS? Otherwise you could look into using a Python script to do the same process.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can have a look at the extension Qpackage. It is acually meant to collect your whole project with all the loaded vectordata from different sources into a single folder. But you can choose a new CRS there. This means open all your files -> say Qpackage the new folder and the new crs -> in the new folder are the reprojected files

Comment: it seems also good solution, i will try this later for sure